# Why does qmake add -O1 and -O2 optimization flags in this case?

Tags: c++, gcc, qmake

I am trying to pass optimization flags to **gcc** using the **qmake .pro file**:

**hello.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O3 \
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compilation output:

> 15:14:34: Running steps for project TestGrounds...
>   15:14:34: Starting:
>   "/usr/bin/make" clean rm -f main.o 
>   rm -f *~ core *.core 
>   15:14:34: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally. 
>   15:14:34: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step. 
>   15:14:34: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
>   g++ -c -pipe **-O3 -O2** -Wall -W -fPIE -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../../Projects/TestGrounds -I. -o main.o ../../Projects/TestGrounds/main.cpp 
>   g++ -Wl,**-O1** -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc -o TestGrounds main.o  
>   15:14:35: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally. 
>   15:14:35: Elapsed time: 00:01.

But why are the **-O1** and **-O2** optimization flags passed too?

I tried to clean the project and rebuild it and the result is the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE *= -O3
```

Comment: fixed that `*=` for you :-)

Comment: Thank you! This removed the initial -O2 flag, but the second one is still there. Also I would like to know why are those flags there in the first place.

Comment: bad fix :-(, because if somewhere -O3 was applied we gain duplicates. *= - will only be added to the list if it is not already defined. @rubenvb please return back my version ).

Comment: @DeadWarlock my bad then. I was not aware of `*=`. Sorry about the mess.

Comment: because qmake has own default flags for building projects and generate make files with them. You can find place where they applied, change on own and rebuild qmake.exe (and Qt library if need)). -O1 still there because they defined perhaps in another variable not in QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE

Comment: And please do you know why g++ is called twice with different flags? Is the first call the compiler and the second call the linker?

Comment: Yes, second must be linker. I do not know exactly, but _-Wl_ is linker command:-). You can try change QMAKE_LFLAGS variable for **-O1**.

Answer (score 13):

There an easier option now, add this in the project settings:

```
CONFIG += optimize_full
```

Or in your .pro:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    CONFIG += optimize_full
}
```

It will replace the -O2 with -O3. (seems to be there since 2014)

Comment: Works fine. Is this an official feature? Is it documented somewhere?